# Translation into english

Tags: questions, translation, phrasal-verbs, portuguese

which one is the correct translation of this sentence in Portuguese? “Ela subiu a escada correndo para me trazer a carta.” 
None of them sound good to me. The best structure in the second one, but one should change the verb take for bring. 
All the other ones sound weird to me, since when we use the verb ‘run’ as gerund as in these sentences, it becomes a noun.

She went running up the stairs to bring me the letter.

She ran up the stairs to take me the letter.

She went up the stairs running to bring me the letter.

She came running up the stairs to bring me the letter.

Comment: If you are at the top of the stairs then I think the last one is the best. 'Came' implies the movement is in the direction of the speaker/writer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because translation questions without a sense of the original are meaningless to those who don’t understand the other language. As a community that focuses on English, we can’t assume that everyone here knows Portuguese.

Comment: U don't have to know Portuguese to read the sentences below the questions, and that's what really matters. The sentence in Portuguese is there for those who know the language. If you're angry 'cos of that, please.. don't underestimate my doubts and lemme be helped by those who are willing to.

Comment: @Lawrence if you don't know Portuguese it's to your detriment, not to the question's. It's a perfectly good question about English phrase structure and semantics.

Comment: @WellLima I can see no anger on Lawrence's part. These are just the rules of the site. That apply to *all* questions here, not just yours. The question has to work *in English*. You are free to supply a Russian translation if you wish. But the question still has to work without it. Right now yours does not. Lawrence didn't just call your attention to the fact, but actually gave you pointers on how to accomplish it. I wouldn't dismiss their advice as harshly, especially not as a newcomer. Thank you. As an aside, there are no gerunds here. A gerund is a participle that works as a noun.

Answer (score 1):

Romance languages have "motion" verbs like *baixar*, *subir*, etc., which primarily describe the *direction* of motion (up or down), and appear as the inflected verb in numerous idiomatic expressions. Comparable English expressions instead use a motion verb that primarily describes *manner* of motion as the inflected verb. The directional component, if included, is the adverb *up* or *down*. It is a difference in semantics.

So in addition to your example: *Ela subiu a escada correndo* (literally *She ascended the stairs running*), which corresponds to "She ran up the stairs." You find numerous others, like in French *Montez le blanc d'un oeuf en neige* (literally *Ascend the white of an egg in snow*) corresponding to "Whip an egg white into soft peaks." In both cases the Romance language construction has a direction-of-motion verb as the inflected verb, while the English construction has a manner-of-motion verb as the inflected verb.

Comment: It's a question a had to answer. I do get it about the movement, and that's why all the options seemed weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd sentence would not be used by a native speaker English. Not knowing the context, it is possible that a non-native speaker is using the sentence.

The same could be said of the second sentence, simply because of the word "take." A native speaker would use "bring" instead of take. Using "bring" would make this a statement used in an informal or familiar setting. (i.e. two guys having a conversation).

The first and fourth are poetic or formal sentences that we might see in literature.

Hopefully, this distinction is useful to you.
$0.02

Comment: Tks a lot! Very useful :)